# Are there windows-style directory shortcuts in Linux at all?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I'm looking for a shortcut that will take me to a directory in Linux. What I want is that if I `cd <my shortcut>` it's the same as if I `cd <the thing to which it points>`.

On Windows if I use a file > open dialog in any program, and navigate through a shortcut, that's the same as if I navigated through the original directory.

In short, it behaves the same as the original directory.  This is different to symbolic links, since those are actually part of the directory structure.  So `cd ~/mysymlink` makes my path `~/mysymlink`, rather than perhaps `/originaldirectory`.

I'm personally using Linux Mint, though I'm making this question about Linux in general.

Comment: You can't type `cd myPath.lnk` in Windows. The best you can do is use a shorthand like `cd %appdata%` which is different from a link and just a environment variable. The latter is available the same in Linux. The first isn't as the function doesn't even exist in Windows.

Comment: Okay, well I hear what you're saying, but as described is what I'm looking.

Answer (score 2):

Set `-P` before following a symlink. For example:

```
$ ln -s /home/youruser/Desktop /tmp/alternative
$ cd /tmp/alternative
$ pwd
/tmp/alternative

$ set -P
$ cd /tmp/alternative
$ pwd
/home/youruser/Desktop
```

From `man bash builtins`:

```
-P      If set, the shell does not resolve symbolic  links  when
        executing  commands  such  as cd that change the current
        working  directory.   It  uses  the  physical  directory
        structure instead.  By default, bash follows the logical
        chain of  directories  when  performing  commands  which
        change the current directory.
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that given this:

```
$ mkdir directory
$ ln -s directory link
```

when you change the current directory to the link:

```
$ pwd
/home/ray
$ cd link
$ pwd
/home/ray/link
```

it remembers the link name and not the real directory name?

If so, you can set an option to alter this behaviour:

```
$ set -o physical
$ pwd
/home/ray
$ cd link
$ pwd
/home/ray/directory
```

That does it for bash-type shells.
For tcsh-type shells, `set symlinks=chase`.

If this isn't what you are asking about, please give an explicit example of what you do, what the result is, and what you wanted the result to be.

Comment: The problem is as you described.  Your solution worked in bash, but didn't work in my file manager (Nemo).  Seems to me that that's a specific problem with my file manager, and therefore an other question entirely.  The getting bash to do it right was the hard part, and I can probably find a work around now that I have this.

Comment: Would you mind just giving me something to Google as to what I just did with that command though?  Do I need to run it at startup every time, or am I good now?  I'm not familiar with it.

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @DuncanMarshall, put the command into your `~/.bashrc` file.  For documentation, `man bash` and look for "-o physical" in the description of "pwd" (line 3414 on my system).